# The existence of a sentence which ensures isomorphism

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Let $\mathcal{L}=\{P\}$ where $P$ is a unary relation symnbol and let $\mathcal{M}$ a finite $\mathcal{L}$-structure. Show that there exists $\sigma \in Sent_{\mathcal{L}}$ such that for all $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{N}$, we have

$$\mathcal{N} \vDash \sigma \text{ if and only if } \mathcal{M} \cong \mathcal{N}$$

I am having issues with this problem, I have tried to prove it by supposing the oposite and reaching a contradiction, also I have tried to prove it directly with some possible sentences, but I don't get it. Possible ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: So basically the structure is an $n$-set with a distinguished $k$-subset. So $\sigma$ has to describe that situation.... I don't think it's too hard to write a rather complicated sentence that does the trick.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Okay, that helps, thanks